# Load partitioned BigQuery table from partitioned ORC

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, orc

I want to create a BigQuery partitioned table by `mydate` column from partitioned ORC.

Files in GCS :

```
mydate=2021-04-01/*.orc
...
mydate=2021-04-30/*.orc
```

Command bq:

```
bq load --source_format=ORC --time_partitioning_field mydate --time_partitioning_type DAY mydataset.mytable gs://mydata/*.orc
```

When I run this command I have this error : `The field specified for partitioning cannot be found in the schema` because `mydate` is not in ORC file.

How can I manage that?

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can do this by Providing a custom partition key schema encoded via the source_uri_prefix field.

Using below links and examples [1] & [2] related to Partition Schema detection modes, I think you can do it.
[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs#command-line-tool
[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs